# looking Rapid application development / application builder for non programmers

Tags: development-environment

is there any tool that can produce me simple application something like access
but without the need for access or open office to be installed 
some thing that will save the data in real stand alone executable file with embedded simple db for non programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Filemaker](http://www.filemaker.com/index.html) does what you want. It's not free, however you could always download the trial and see if it fits.

Comment: If you want to distribute standalone apps, you'll need the 'Developer' version of FilemakerPro.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Access, you should look into compiling it into a standalone app using the Access runtime. [Here's](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Access/microsoft.public.access.devtoolkits/2005-01/0046.html) a thread on it.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that non-programmers will be quite limited in what they'll be able to accomplish, so calling this "rapid application development" is probably way overstating things.